# Count formula for 2 sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

i want formula for count of accounts from sheet 2 if accounts name matches in both sheet account column and put value in count column

[image]

Comment: The mockup is appreciated but I would encourage you to include column and row references if looking for a formula

Answer (score 0):

#### COUNTIFS

Returns the count of a range depending on multiple criteria.

```
   Function:
   ---------
   =COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, …], [criterion2, …])
```

**Sample Table:**

```
         A         B         C         D         E
   --+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-
   1 | Account |  Count  |         | Account | Status  |
   --+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-
   2 |   MNC   |    2    |         |   MNC   |    Y    |
   --+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-
   3 |   BLC   |         |         |   MNC   |    N    |
   --+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-
   4 |   BTS   |         |         |   MNC   |    Y    |
   --+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-
```

**Formula in B3**
We want to `COUNT` rows if `columnD = A2` and also if `Column E = "Y"`

```
  =COUNTIFS(D:D,A2,E:E,"Y")
```

This formula can be copied into each row in `column B`

```
         A                   B              
   --+---------+----------------------------+-
   1 | Account |         Count              |
   --+---------+----------------------------+-
   2 |   MNC   | =COUNTIFS(D:D,A2,E:E,"Y")  |
   --+---------+----------------------------+-
   3 |   BLC   | =COUNTIFS(D:D,A3,E:E,"Y")  |
   --+---------+----------------------------+-
   4 |   BTS   | =COUNTIFS(D:D,A4,E:E,"Y")  |
   --+---------+----------------------------+-
   5 |   MSC   | =COUNTIFS(D:D,A5,E:E,"Y")  |
   --+---------+----------------------------+-
```